# add values ​of selected radio buttons and output / process the sum

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I would like to add the values ​​of selected radio buttons and output / process the sum at the end .. Does anyone have a tip why the following does not work?
Thank you from a Noob!

```
 <html>
<head>


</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcPrice() {
  var price = 0;
  $("input[type=radio][data-price]:checked").each(function(i, el) {
    price += +$(el).data("price");
  });
  $("#price").text(price);
}

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", calcPrice);
calcPrice();

</script>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Group 1:</p><ol>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group1" checked>Item 1 (frei)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group1" data-price="1">Item 2 (€1)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group1" data-price="2">Item 3 (€2)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group1" data-price="3">Item 4 (€3)</li></label>
</ol>

<p>Group 2:</p><ol>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group2" data-price="20" checked>Another item 1 (€20)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group2" data-price="0">Another item 2 (frei)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group2" data-price="5">Another item 3 (€5)</li></label>
<label><li><input type="radio" name="group2" data-price="10">Another item 4 (€10)</li></label>
</ol>

<p>Total: €<span id="price">--.--</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems to be fine. Please ensure that your javascript is placed after when jquery gets loaded. Right now you have your code in the head and jquery in body. Try checking the console in your browser's developer tools. If this is the problem you will see an error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Comment: ok thx, i now have put the jquery loading in the head before the javascript, but its still not working. in the firebug>Console there is no warning. Any other possible solution?

Comment: @Alderim This code worked fine on my system so the problem might be related to your environment. Try using console.log statements after each step to track down the issue. If you know how to use a debugger that would be optimal.